# How to Delete Blob From Private Azure Blob Storage Container

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to delete a blob from a private blob container using the `deleteBlobIfExists()` function from the `azure-storage` npm package. But, when the function is executed, the `result` always comes back as `false`, which means the blob "doesn't exist". But the blob does exist.  I'm just assuming that it can't find the blob because the container's access is set to "private". Help?

```
const blobService = azure.createBlobService();
blobService.deleteBlobIfExists("my-blob-container", "my-blob", (err, result) => {
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
});
```

Comment: Have you made sure your connection options using `azure.createBlobService()` are correct, why don't you try and query for `my-blob` with the same BlobService.

Comment: If your container's access level is private, please use ```azure.createBlobService(<connection string>)``` to create the blob service. For more details, please refer to https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/global.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a race condition with Azure if you're calling this shortly after a blob creation event.

Comment: Yes, this is what it was.  I had written a method to delete any blobs that I had just added to Azure if other logic in my API endpoint failed.  Since I had just barely created the blobs, the `doesExist` method was returning false everytime.  I got around this by using a setInterval() and calling the method a couple of times after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If your container's access level is private, you need to provide storage connection string  or account name and account key when you use `azure.createBlobService()` to create blob client.

Besides, The sdk `azure-storage` is Azure Storage nodejs V2. It is a legacy SDK. I suggest you use the sdk [`@azure/storage-blob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob). It is the latest SDK. Regarding how to use it, please refer to the following steps

1. create sp

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n <your-application-name> --skip-assignment
az keyvault set-policy --name <your-key-vault-name> --spn $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --secret-permissions backup delete get list purge recover restore set
```

2. create .env file

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID=<tenant id>
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=<app id>
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=<password>
```

3. install package

```
npm install @azure/identity
npm install @azure/storage-blob
```

4. code

```
var storage = require("@azure/storage-blob")
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");

const defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const blobclient = new storage.BlobServiceClient("<blob url>",defaultAzureCredential)
  if(blobClient.exists()){

    blobClient.delete()

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm with what Jim Xu is saying - add your connection string when calling

```
azure.createBlobService()
```

and it deletes the blob successfully. I tried with the quickstart sample code and was able to successfully delete a blob in a private container.

```
const CONNECT_STR = process.env.CONNECT_STR;
console.log('\nDeleting blob...');

// Delete blob
const blobService = azure.createBlobService(CONNECT_STR);
blobService.deleteBlobIfExists(containerName, blobName, (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
       console.log(err);
    }
 });

console.log("Blob was deleted successfully.");
```

Comment: The documentation says that ```createBlobService``` "Creates a new {@link BlobService} object. If no storageaccount or storageaccesskey are provided, the AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING and then the AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT and AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY environment variables will be used."  I have the connection string in my .env file and I'm able to create the blob service just fine.